# importing sage function errors

Tags: function, package, cython, sage

I have a .spyx file that i'm running with using sage.

I have this:

```
from sage.all import *
```

which has been handling built-in sage functions like: complement(), clique_number(), and graph(). BUT, it absolutely does not recognize **chromatic_number()**, even thought it is part of the sage library package.

I have also tried:

```
from sage.graphs import *
```

Which is redundant, and not working.

What do I do?

Comment: I couldn't even get it to recognize `graphs`, but I would wonder if maybe something needs to be `cimport`ed?

Comment: I'm not sure. I was under the assumption that:    from sage.all import * imports the entire sage library.

Comment: Right, but you are using a Cython-ish file there.  You may find http://ask.sagemath.org/question/289/compiling-spyx-files.  Although actually you shouldn't need to `import *` in an *s*pyx file, only in a pyx file.

Comment: It's working now...somehow? I had commented out a redundant line `from sage.graphs.graph_coloring import chromatic_number` that I had put in after some frustrating errors saying it doesn't understand chromatic_number().

Comment: Great!  (?)  Can you put a minimal (non)-working example of this, just for future visitors to this question?

Comment: I figured it out. I guess I used `attach myfile.spyx` and then used vi to edit in `chromatic_number()`. What you apparently have to do is do `load myfile.spyx` again or reattach it. I hope that is a good enough answer/example for those incoming.